# Explaining lift on a wing using forces

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Consider the bottom of a wing.

Air below the wing is deflected downwards by the wing. Hence by Newton's 3rd Law the wind must exert an equal and opposite force on the wing. Hence lift, and this makes logical sense.

What becomes confusing, is explaining how lift is created at the top of the wing. Air once again moves down the top of the wing. However, now it doesn't make sense to say the wing is exerting a downwards force on the wind, because clearly it is below the wind. How do we get around this?

Bernoullis principle, visocity, and pressure can all explain this, but how do we do this soley in terms of forces? What force is causing the wind to move downwards at the top?

Comment: Air above the wing is also deflected downward.